# Why is my UITextField delegate method not called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, delegates, uitextfield

Here's my problem. I created a UITextField.

.h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *emailTextField;
```

.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.emailTextField.delegate=self;
  [self setTextFields:120 :@"  email" :self.emailTextField];
}

-(void)setTextFields:(float)ycoord :(NSString *)text :(UITextField *)textField
{
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(60, ycoord, 180, 30);
  textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
  textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  textField.placeholder = text;
  textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville" size:15];
  textField.allowsEditingTextAttributes=YES;
  textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

  CALayer *lay = [textField layer];
  [lay setCornerRadius:5.0f];
  [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```

The aim is to save the text that the user put in the TextField. I tried with the delegate method

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

but the method is not called (I put a NSLog to check). Could someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.emailTextField= [self setTextFields:120 :@"  email"];
  self.emailTextField.delegate=self;

  self.passwordTextField= [self setTextFields:200 :@"  password"];
  self.passwordTextField.delegate=self;

  self.nameTextField= [self setTextFields:250 :@"  name"];
  self.nameTextField.delegate=self;
 }

-(UITextField *)setTextFields:(float)ycoord :(NSString *)text{

  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(60, ycoord, 180, 30);

  UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
  textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  textField.placeholder = text;
  textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville" size:15];
  textField.allowsEditingTextAttributes=YES;
  textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

  CALayer *lay = [textField layer];
  [lay setCornerRadius:5.0f];
  [self.view addSubview:textField];
  return textField;
  }
```

Comment: I have other textField (self.passwordTextField and self.nameTextField). That's why I am using a function. So I can't put your lines into my code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You set the delegate for emailTextField but when you create a UITextField you set textField.  This could work if you @synthesize emailTextField to textField.
2. Assuming that you are doing an @synthesize between emailTextFiled and textField or you change emailTextField to just textField, you are setting the delegate before you have created the object.  You need to move setting the delegate until after you called setTextFields:

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues:

You're setting the delegate before you actually create the `UITextField`.

When you create a `UITextField` in your `setTextFields:` method, you're never assigning it to your property. All you're doing is passing `nil` in to your method, and when you assign a value to the variable in your method, you're only assigning it within the context of that method. It doesn't go back and set the property.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the way InterfaceBuilder builds the view.

Try a [MyTextFieldDelegate new] at application launch.
Your class will then be registered and correctly binded to the fields when your view is awaked from NIB.